# Text After Comment Form

Tags: 7, comments

How I could put a block of text after my comment form (kinda like politics), I put comments separated from the content (different pages).

Comment: could you be more explicit on where you want the text, for all the comments forms ? the same text ?

Answer (score 3):

As megadesk mentioned its [`hook_form_alter`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) you're after.

Depending on what your more comfortable with you can either add this to your theme in template.php or you can add it to a module. I'm going to assume from now on that you'r putting it into template.php. An infact rather than hook_form_alter we'll use hook_form_FORM_ID_alter.

```
/*
* Implementation of hook_form_FORM_ID_alter
* 
* Adding text after the comment form
*/

function YOUR_MODULE_NAME_form_comment_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {

    //add an I agree to house rules checkbox to the form
    $form['markup'] = array(
                 //This is the text you want to add to the form, using the t() function allows it to be translatable
                '#markup' => t('You can leave us a message using the contact form below.'),
                //By making the weight 20 we insure that it appears at the bottom of the form
                '#weight' => 20,
        );
}
```

I havnt tested this but that should be what your after... Let me know if you need more.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use hook_form_alter.
http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7

Here is a little Tutorial for that:
http://www.digett.com/blog/05/26/2011/how-theme-comment-form-drupal-7

Comment: Answers that are just a little more than a link are not considered answers, on Stack Exchange.

Comment: Sorry, didn't know that. Just wanted to push him in the right direction. I think in the tutorial is all described what he needs. Will try better next time.